# summernote image appending outside editor

Tags: php, ajax, summernote

I am using summernote for some text editing and all. I am using akax calls to upload image to my server. Everything works fine only problem being when Image is being uploaded and before server sends back response if I click outside the textarea then summernote appends image outside the editor instead within the editor.

Any suggestions or any one faced similar issue?

Comment: You can open an issue here: https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues